# How to the center the title and put a bar of colour behind it?

Tags: html, css

This is my code. It starts off in HTML and the other half is CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title>
Home - Hasan's Website
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navigation">
            <a class="active" href = "#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
            <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
            <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
        </div>

    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>

    </div>




    </body>
</html>



    body, html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:1.8em;

}
.navigation {
    background-color: #330;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;

}

.navigation a {

    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;

}

.navigation a:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    color: black;
}

.navigation a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

body {

    background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}

h1 {

    margin: auto;
    z-index: 4;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    padding: 10px;



}
```

I really need help putting the Computer engineering title in the center of the background image, also I want a bar of colour behind it. Can anyone please help me? This stuff is due tomorrow!

Comment: is there more content below the title?

Comment: nope, there is no content below the title yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add bar image address in jumbotron css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>
    Home - Hasan's Website
  </title>
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }
    
    .jumbotron {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background-image: url(gg.jpg);
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 1px;
    }
    
    .navigation {
      background-color: #330;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    }
    
    .navigation a {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .navigation a:hover {
      background-color: #dddddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .navigation a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
    
    body {
      background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 4;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      color: white;
      font-size: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
    <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
  </div>

  <div class="intro">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>

    </div>


  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

[image: see this]

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a god! There is just one tiny problem though. The part where it is supposed to be red and blue, it is just replaced by the background, so there are two backgrounds on top of each other. https://gyazo.com/9692c17193bee59abf8d8fec1a25cda1?token=331864eab98359ee854cb34f85ef8a7a

Comment: Background is same for both the page and jumbotron, hence the overlapping, if you would like, you could remove jumbotron backround and add opacity to it, so it will be visible and look cool too. Add this:
.jumbotron {
   background: rgb(200, 54, 54); 
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); 
}

Comment: Thank you so much. I clicked the green check mark. I think that marks your answer as right.